# In Cognos 8.4 BI/FM, how can I change the schema of a model?

Tags: cognos-bi, cognos-8

When I used Framework Manager to create a data model, I specified a schema to be used such as `XYZ_PAX` (each developer gets their own schema). However, when we ship the package to customers, it will be required to use the standard schema for the product, `XYX`.

I pushed the model out to Cognos 8.4 BI but I cannot find any place where the schema can be changed in Framework Manager.

Every dialog box in Framework Manager for editing properties simply lists the data source rather than the schema. And there's nothing I can find in the data source definition under Cognos to indicate that it is being used to set a specific schema.

How do I go about changing the schema in Framework Manager? I'd rather not have to rebuild the entire model from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it turns out that the schema specification is contained in the `model.xml` file.

You can simply open this file with your favourite editor and replace the old schema name `XYZ_PAX` with whatever you need, such as `XYZ`.

Then you open the CPF project file in Framework Manager and republish. This will push the changed model out to the Cognos server.

Any reports then created will use the new model and you can open up each existing report in Report Studio and it will automatically revalidate with the new model. Just remember to save the report design when finished.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using synonyms in your database?